# In Rails, how to pass parameters to controller method from Jquery and then get returned values?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails4, I have an method named `get_values_from_models` in **Controller** which take an parameter `id`:

### app/controller/bugs_controller.rb

```
def get_values_from_models(id)
  @online_bugs = Bugs.where(bug_id: id)
  @devlopers = Devs.where(dev_role_id: 2)
end
```

I would like to call this method **within** the Jquery function`show_bug_detail`, which is in an partial view:

### app/view/bugs/_get_values.html.erb

```
var id =5;
function show_bug_detail(id) {
  //call method get_values_from_models, pass parameters 'id'
  //get @online_bugs and @developers instances from returned.
  }
```

Is that possible? How to do that?
I have been searching the possible solutions for a while but without any fortune, it would be appreciate if someone can provide me any solution, thanks.

Comment: You need to use Ajax for this. Make a route to connect to the controller action you want to call. Then using Ajax call the controller action and return data from the action to the Jquery and use it.

Comment: You are correct, It turns out I should use Ajax to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Now note that for example purposes I've created the route as a collection. However, since this really is an action on the resource itself it would make more sense to create a member out of it. Perhaps you should look at that? This would create a route like /bugs/:id/get_values_from_models*

I did not test the following code myself, but this is the basic idea.

Create a route for it, let's say:

(Also see the rails guides for reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)

```
resources :bugs do
  get get_values_from_models, on: :collection
end
```

I don't know when your function is triggered, but when it is you can put in the following code to fetch your results with an ajax get.

Also see the jQuery API for reference: 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get("bugs/get_values_from_models", {id: your_id}, function(data){
  // do something with your data received if everything went ok.
  // notice that you'll have to return json from your controller.
}, "json");
```

Make your method "get_values_from_models" accessible (so not private). Remove the id as a parameter. So something like this:

```
def get_values_from_models
  # when called you should receive a params[:id]
  id = params[:id]

  @online_bugs = Bugs.where(bug_id: id)
  @developers = Devs.where(dev_role_id: 2)

  # now return the results you'd like
  render json: {online_bugs: @online_bugs, developers: @developers}
end
```

Comment: This helped me immensely. Thanks.